# Installing LAStools in QGIS 2.4?

Tags: qgis, installation, lidar, qgis-2.4, lastools

Does anyone know where the Processing menu moved in QGIS 2.4? Specifically, I am trying to install the LAStools box for QGIS following these instructions:

http://rapidlasso.com/2013/09/29/how-to-install-lastools-toolbox-in-qgis/

Comment: It should still be in the same place - but check if the plugin is active! "Plugins|Manage and Install Plugins" menu.

Comment: I followed your direction, but still the window can't find the missing dependency. any suggestion?

Answer (score 7):

For QGIS 2.4.0, you don't have to install the Lidar toolbox; it is installed by default.

What you have to do:

- Make sure `Processing` is enabled in `Plugins -> Manage and install Plugins`
- activate the `Advanced interface` at the bottom of the processing toolbox
- enable the Lidar toolbox in `Processing -> Options and configuration -> Providers -> Tools for LIDAR data`