# Installing LAStools in QGIS 3.0?

Tags: qgis, installation, lidar, qgis-3, lastools

I don't know how to install LAStools in QGIS 3.0. In QGIS 2.18, you can incorporate it as a provider in Processing -> Options-> Tools for LiDAR data (for example: [Installing LAStools in QGIS 2.4?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108699/installing-lastools-in-qgis-2-4/108712#108712)).

But in the QGIS 3.0, you can only find GRASS, GDAL and SAGA in the same place.

Does anyone knows how to install LAStools in QGIS 3.0?

Answer (score 9):

Install QGIS 3.2 and goto the plugin manager. A brand-spanking new set of LAStools toolboxes can be found by searching for LAStools in the Plugin repository or download the latest version here:

http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/LAStools/

[image: screenshot during development in Zanzibar]

Comment: Are there docs for it anywhere? I don't see those options in my processing toolbox after installing the plugin.

Comment: I'm not sure how to even view an .las file either.

Comment: In addition you will have to download the *actual* LAStools software from http://rapidlasso.com/LAStools and then set the correct "LAStools Folder" in the Provider settings to the path of where you unzipped the LAStools.zip file too.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, to set the LASTools Folder in the Provider settings, you click on the wrench (settings) icon in the Processing Toolbox panel. The last choice in the left menu column is a gear labeled Processing. Click this, then expand the providers in the right pane of the settings dialog. Here's where you'll find LASTools and a place to set the path.

Answer (score 6):

The Lidartools provider was removed from QGIS 3.0. See the QGIS 3.0.0 changelog: http://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.0.0/#removed-otb-lidartools-providers-from-processing

As long as nobody makes a QGIS plugin to add Lidartools as a processing provider, it isn't possible to use LASTools in QGIS 3.0.

Comment: ouch, get on it isenburg

Comment: I saw that in the changelog as well and was disappointed that there was no explanation for the removal. #gomapping - it's not just a matter of getting the tools from another source, it's about the integration with QGIS that I am concerned. I'd like to stay in the one environment.

Comment: I looked at the code, and because of switching to python3 and due to changes in the API of Qt5 and PyQt5 plus a new model for Plugin Provider which isn't documented (cookbook) at the moment, it will be a job for an expert from the "inner circle" of qgis developers.

Comment: @gomapping [He's already on it](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lastools/KMqCrBF7E88)....maybe we'll get lucky be the end of summer.