# Unable to install FUSION in QGIS 3.2?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation, lidar, fusion

I'm unable to install FUSION in QGIS 3.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Andre Silva on [Creating DEM from LAS file without using LAStools?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181712) says to use the same procedure as LAStools (up to QGIS 2.18 version). I've previously installed LAStools which work great. But I don't get how to do it for Fusion.

I've installed the Fusion .exe with Wine correctly. Then, as said in [how to install LAStools toolbox in QGIS](https://rapidlasso.com/2013/09/29/how-to-install-lastools-toolbox-in-qgis/), unzip the FUSION plugin folder and paste it in QGIS plugin folder even if it is said to be only used for QGIS 2.2, but there is none for 3.2 (it is a 2013 post).

Nothing appears in QGIS toolbox bar or advanced configuration. Maybe it is because I've already installed LAStools. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in [Installing LAStools in QGIS 3.0?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273300/installing-lastools-in-qgis-3-0/273320#273320), it is no longer possible to connect LAStools and FUSION as providers in the Processing plugin since QGIS versions 3+ .

According to the [QGIS change log](http://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.0.0/#removed-otb-lidartools-providers-from-processing) the way to go now is:

> The new logic will be to develop plugin providers that will be able to follow the external software lifecycle.

LAStools has its own QGIS plugin ([QGIS reference](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/LAStools/); [GitHub](https://github.com/rapidlasso/LAStoolsPluginQGIS3)), so as FUSION ([QGIS reference](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/processing_fusion/); [GitHub](https://github.com/biglimp/qgis-fusion)).

The `FUSION for Processing` plugin is only available for Windows. It works the same way as the LAStools plugin, which means one needs both the plugin and the core software installed. See: [LAStools plugin in QGIS: ''The system cannot find the path specified."](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307116/lastools-plugin-in-qgis-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified/307213#307213)

Comment: Thanks Andre for the precisions
Can I use FUSION with its own GUI ?

Comment: @JDB, you are welcome. FUSION only has A GUI for LiDAR data viewing, not processing. But it is straightforward using its tools through the command-line syntax. Take a look, for example, in the following posts: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53483/finding-outliers-with-wrong-z-values-in-lidar-data/54517#54517, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86075/clipping-las-data-using-shapefile-polygons-and-open-source-software/86160#86160.