# LAStools plugin in QGIS: ''The system cannot find the path specified."

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation, lidar, lastools

I'm attempting to convert LAS files to a multipoint file using QGIS methods. I've found some documentation that suggests that v3.2 and up has LAStools available as a plugin so I downloaded the latest version (3.4) of QGIS to explore this more.

You can see below the tool that I'm attempting to use here in the processing toolbox:

[image]

I have yet to be able to run this successfully. I'm not very familiar with QGIS so I'm having trouble finding documentation to explain the LAS tool sets.

Here is my input:

[image]

And here is the output:

[image]

The error message appearing says that I cannot find the path specified. Is this in reference my las file or to something within the LAS plugin?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Be aware one needs to have the LAStools plugin installed, but also the software per se.

The LAStools plugin description says:

> ... . You also need to download the LAStools software from http://rapidlasso.com/LAStools/

Once plugin and software are installed, make sure to set its path accordingly (as suggested in [john's comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307116/how-do-i-convert-las-files-to-a-multipoint-file-uisng-qgis#comment497072_307116)):

[image]