# Get density map of points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a point cloud in .las and I would like to get a **raster map that shows the number of point per m²**.
The idea is to know how many point per m² (2D) my .las contains in order to know the 2D density of the point cloud.
Is there a function in QGIS that could do this?

The .las point cloud can be transform in others format like .txt

Comment: QGIS can handle .las files (I think it automatically converts it). Just to clarify, are you looking at calculating the point cloud density per meter cubed or by meter squared as you state based on their 2D position?

Comment: Try plugin LAStools: https://github.com/rapidlasso/LAStoolsPluginQGIS3 see also https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/307213/88814

Comment: I've edited my main post : I'm looking for  the density of the point cloud by meter squared based on their 2D XY position.