# LASTools path not found in QGIS 3.6.3

Tags: qgis, lastools

Forgive me if this is a duplicate, but I am having trouble getting LASTools to run in QGIS 3.6.3 after following the [installation instructions](https://rapidlasso.com/2013/09/29/how-to-install-lastools-toolbox-in-qgis/) and [searching on Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273300/installing-lastools-in-qgis-3-0).

I have installed the LASTools plugin in QGIS and set the path from the Options menu to my LASTools extracted folder. I've tried several locations all with no luck. For information, I have tested the paths in Finder, which seems to navigate fine.

Here is my output when running LASTools:

```
LAStools command line
/Applications/QGIS3.6.app/Contents/Resources/LAStools/bin/lasclassify -i "/Volumes/My Book/Photos/CNPS los osos map/osos.las"

LAStools console output
/bin/sh: /Applications/QGIS3.6.app/Contents/Resources/LAStools/bin/lasclassify: No such file or directory
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you running Qgis on a Mac? As far as I know, executable files from lastools do not work on IOS.

Comment: If this the case, check this from the lastools oficial blog: https://rapidlasso.com/2014/10/04/using-lastools-on-mac-os-x-with-wine/

Comment: If you are using windows, lastools folder must reside in like c:\lastools

Comment: Oh, thank you! That's what's I was missing. I am running on Mac.